# Firebase + Flutter business framework

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am considering building a **Firebase + Flutter** framework to small business solutions.

By providing a fairly high level of security, Firebase + Flutter seems quite good for a number of business applications especially based on Android.
However, for this to make sense I have to solve a few problems and I will be very grateful for help in any of the points below.

1. Is it possible to connect from within a firebase database via VPN
   (mainly OpenVPN) to another database via odbc and/or through
   webservice (strongly preferred odbc)? The goal is to connect
   firebase with local databases in companies - especially MS-SQL
   databases (mainly small ERP / WMS system). If this is not possible,
   how can an equivalent effect be obtained? I also need a connection
   from firebase to firebase to automatically download changes to the
   framework from the main repository.
2. Many governmental and commercial systems require signing files with
   a signature based on X.509 (mainly * .pfx, * .p12 password
   protected). I would like all such a signature to be implemented on
   the firebase server side (possibility of managing such
   certificates). Are there appropriate libraries in firebase to sign
   content in accordance with X.509? If not how to get the effect of
   signing content in firebase + flutter and strongly prefer that the
   certificate was not on the client.
3. In several places on the network I met the possibility of logging in
   using a certificate compatible with X.509 or identical, but I do not
   see such an option for selection in the panel in firebase? Is
   X.509-compliant login support by Google in Firebase, and if not,
   could I ask for a step-by-step link on how to handle it yourself in
   two variants: a) external certificate , b) automatically generated
   certificate by the client application.

Thank you in advance for your support

Answer (score 0):

The subject of this question is so broad that I don't think its possible to answer on StackOverflow.

Generally Firebase is a set of cloud functionalities including databases, functions, authentication (and many more) that can be used in your mobile apps. One of the technologies that you can use Firebase with, but not only one, is Flutter which is engine using Dart programing language. But there are a lot of API from other programing languages like Java, JS, Python and many more. They might be different depending of the product you choose from Firebase.

Now pointing to your questions:

1. I am not sure what do you mean by "connecting from Firebase", but I suppose you mean connecting from your app. If you build the app in Flutter you will use Dart and it has VPN support of course like [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_vpn).
2. Although I don't know much about X.509 I have found that dart will support it as well here [example](https://pub.dev/packages/x509csr).
3. Authentication is one of Firebase [enter link description here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) products. You can find there also [custom authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth) possibilities

I think all you asking is possible, but of course there is no simple answer for it. I hope it will help you.